# Is there any way to close down Chrome inspect console permanently? I am facing problem while browsing coz inspect element getting open again and again

Tags: inspect-element

I am facing Inspect console problem on chrome. It's getting open again and agai.Is there any way to close it down permanently? I tried to solve using ctrl+shift+i shortcut but it didn't work